# BOOT COMPLETE BroadcastReceiver automatically being registered

Tags: android, kotlin, service, broadcastreceiver, boot

I am trying to start my service when the user wants the service to start on boot. So I have a checkbox preference on my settings fragment to control it. When the box is checked and the user starts the service, the `StartOnBootBroadcast` BroadcastReceiver will be registered and it will start the service after boot is completed. By default the BroadcastReceiver will not be registered unless the user wants it. But the problem is If I install the app and restarts my device, the broadcast receiver starts the service (BUT I NEVER REGISTERED IT). I've checked the condition with debugger and the conditions never met for starting the receiver.

**Broadcast receiver:**

```kotlin
class StartOnBootBroadcast : BroadcastReceiver() {

    companion object {
        private var instance: StartOnBootBroadcast? = null
        fun getinstance(): StartOnBootBroadcast {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = StartOnBootBroadcast()
            }
            return instance as StartOnBootBroadcast
        }
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        Log.d("BOOTCAST", "onReceive: FIRED")
        
        val serviceIntent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context!!.startForegroundService(serviceIntent)
        } else {
            context!!.startService(serviceIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sourav.bettere">
    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".service.ChargeLoggerService" />

        <receiver android:name=".broadcasts.BatteryBroadcast">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".broadcasts.ChargingBroadcast">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".broadcasts.StartOnBootBroadcast">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Methods for registering / unregistering the BroadcastReciever:**

```kotlin
prefViewmodel.getBootStatus.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { value ->
    onBoot = value
        if (Utilities.getInstance(mContext).isMyServiceRunning(ChargeLoggerService::class.java)){
            startOnBoot(onBoot)
        }
})

////unrelated codes

switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                startService()
                Utilities.getInstance(mContext)
                    .writeToPref(
                        Constants.PREF_TYPE_BOOL,
                        Constants.PREF_LOGGER_ACTIVE,
                        valueBool = true
                    )
            } else {
                stopService()
                Utilities.getInstance(mContext)
                    .writeToPref(
                        Constants.PREF_TYPE_BOOL,
                        Constants.PREF_LOGGER_ACTIVE,
                        valueBool = false
                    )
            }
            startOnBoot(onBoot)
        }

private fun startOnBoot(value: Boolean){
        when(value){
            true -> Utilities.getInstance(mContext).loadBroadcastReceiver(startOnBoot, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
            false -> {
                try {
                    requireContext().unregisterReceiver(startOnBoot)
                }catch (e:Exception){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }}

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "startOnBoot: $value")
    }
```